# One specific application cannot access internet in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet, mobile-broadband

I have one application in my Ubuntu 18.04 OS which cannot access it's server to synchronize data when I'm connected to broadband. But it can connect to server when I'm connected to mobile hotspot. Anyway, I can access their website when connected to both mobile and broadband. How could I analyze the problem on my machine? I tried to play with MTU value on default network interface but it didn't help.
One note, this is not Wine application and I don't have such issues with another applications
Thank you

Comment: @guiverc, it's regular application packaged in .deb package. It's not Wine application, there was a typo, sorry

Comment: It's as likely to be the server rather than anything on your side.  You haven't mentioned the name of the application, which makes it less likely that you'll get a useful answer.